# How do I swap the two halves of a circular linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list, circular-list

I am working on this code challenge with a circular linked list:

> In class `CLList`, write a function called `swapHalf()` which swaps the first half of the list by the second half. You should cover all the cases.
>
> **Example:**
>
> Before [v,w,t,j,q,o,w,s,w,t]
>
> `swapHalf()`
>
> After [o,w,s,w,t,v,w,t,j,q]

I could only cover the cases where the list has 0 or 2 elements. But for the latter, the list loses an element, and I don't know how to cover for any circular list size:

```
public void swapHalf() {
    CharNode cn;
    if (tail == null) {
        return;
    } else if (tail == tail.next.next) {
         cn = tail;
         cn.setNext(tail);
         cn.next.setNext(tail.next);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to call `setNext`. No node should be mutated -- all the links can remain the same. The only thing that needs to change is what `tail` references.

You could use two node references that traverse the list, but with one moving twice as fast as the other. When the fast one has made a full cycle, the other one will by consequence be half way the list. Then the only thing to do is to set the `tail` reference to that node.

```
public void swapHalf() {
    if (tail == null || tail.next == tail) { // 0 or 1 node
        return;
    }
    CharNode fast = tail.next.next;
    CharNode origTail = tail;
    tail = tail.next
    while (fast != origTail && fast.next != origTail) {
        fast = fast.next.next;
        tail = tail.next;
    }
}
```